# ion-text-center doesn't center the content within ion-item

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic4

```
 <ion-item lines="none" class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-avatar slot="start" *ngFor="let mId of headerMemberIds;let i = index" class="member-{{i}}">
        <img [src]="profilePhotoUrl$[mId] | async">
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-avatar slot="start" class="avatar" *ngIf="allMemberIds?.length>3">
        <div class="remaining-members">+{{allMemberIds?.length-2}}</div>
      </ion-avatar>
    </ion-item>
```

Any clue about how to center the content inside the `ion-item` and of course my use case above?

*Generated css on the browser*

```
.ion-text-center, [text-center] {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class="text-center" and define the class like that :

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You can read it here. This is Ionic 4 related issue: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-modification